# getting all iFrames within a div and resizing them for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

In short, the problem is this: we have a news site that has a mobile version of the website. For the page that displays whatever article is called, occasionally, there are embedded videos (from youtube) that show up in iframes. Their default size is typically something like 580px, which obviously comes out far too big and wide on a mobile browser.

I wanted to use javascript to search the content and resize any iframe as it finds it. That said, I don't know if using JavaScript on mobile will be the best thing to do, and second, I'm not sure how to search for all instances of a certain element type like that. The iframes do not come in with names or IDs...

I briefly considered using PHP to search for `<iframe` but it seems that php, in this instance, would be unnecessarily sloppy and potentially easily broken.

Does anybody have advice/suggestions on how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery it's very easy to select elements based on tag.

jQuery:

```
$('iframe').width(300);
```

Fairly easy using normal DOM as well.

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i=0; i<iframes.length; i++)
    {
      iframes[i].style.width = "300px"
    }
```

Comment: iframes[i].style.width = "300px" is missing a ; and I would suggest to add something like 

 var w = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
 var o = 900;var isMobile = false;
 if(w < o) {isMobile = true;}

 iframes[i].style.width = w-16+'px'; 

:) btw good answer - voted you up :)

Comment: That did it! I made one modification, so that I could get the percentage the iframe width is being reduced by and apply that to the height to retain proportion. Thanks both!: var multiplyBy = 300/parseInt(iframes[i].width);      
iframes[i].width = parseInt(iframes[i].width)*multiplyBy;
iframes[i].height = parseInt(iframes[i].height)*multiplyBy;

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, resizing all iframes on a document would be as simple as typing, for example,

```
$('iframe').css('width', '200px');
```

Sure, jQuery has an overhead in terms of size, but minified and gzipped, its footprint is not so large, even for mobile applications.

Comment: Is jQuery going to be a universal enough solution for mobile phones? I've never used it for mobile, and understood that it was probably best not to. In fact, how safe is even JS itself to use for mobile phones?

Comment: Depends on how you define “universal”, I guess. jQuery mobile supports [quite a lot of platforms](http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/about/platforms.html) (this includes most current smartphones), but if you want something that is completely universal, you may be better off without any Javascript anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Just include the width margin you want at the top:

```
//Just Change this
var margin = "20";
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var w = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var newwidth = w - ( 2 * margin );

for (var i=0; i<iframes.length; i++)
{
 var currentheight = iframes[i].height;
 var currentwidth  = iframes[i].width;  
 var newheight = (newwidth / currentwidth) * currentheight;

  iframes[i].style.width = newwidth+"px";
  iframes[i].style.height = newheight+"px";
}
```